# Highcharts tooltip in scrollable container scrolls with the content

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts instance that is rendered within a scrollable container. The [tooltip.outside](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.outside) option is also set to `true` so that the tooltip is always on top regardless if it fits the chart svg.

When you scroll however, you can see tooltip following the scrolling. Moreover, when you hover over the series, the tooltip renders in various positions.

Is there a way to fix it? FYI if you set `tooltip.outside` to `false` everything works just fine. I'm sure the issue revolves around the fact that when set to `true`, the calculation to determine where to render the tooltip is no longer correct as the position changed with the scrolling.

So to sum up the 2 issues that appear:

1. The tooltip follows the scrolling
2. On re-hovering, the position on the tooltip on the series is wrong.

See gif around the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WeMB.jpg
See example: https://jsfiddle.net/tcqeo415/2/

If you comment out my CSS code in the example, you should be able to see how it *should* work

Comment: I think this bug is about the same issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chart does not recalculate it's position because it does not track the `scroll` event.

To fix this, you can recalculate `chart.pointer.chartPosition.top`. Below code works only for the first chart:

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function (proceed, points) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    this.points = points;
  });
}(Highcharts));

document.getElementById('container1').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
  if (chart && chart.pointer && !chart.startChartPosY) {
    chart.pointer.getChartPosition();
    chart.startChartPosY = chart.pointer.chartPosition.top;
  }
});

document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
  var H = Highcharts,
    chart = H.charts[H.hoverChartIndex],
    tooltip = chart.tooltip;

  if (chart && chart.pointer) {
    chart.pointer.chartPosition.top = chart.startChartPosY - this.scrollTop;
  }

  if (tooltip && !tooltip.isHidden) {
    tooltip.refresh(tooltip.points);
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ao0c21g6/3/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this I appreciate it's not the easiest of problems and some digging is required. I came up with a solution very similar to yours. I will post it as an answer in case anyone wants it but I will gladly accept yours.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is pretty similar to @ppotaczek one in terms of the idea just a different implementation.

When the mouse enters a chart, the chart position is *cached* so if you scroll but your mouse is still within the chart, it doesn't recalculate the position but due to the scrolling the position has changed.

A solution would be to use [tooltip.positioner](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner) and *disable* the caching by `null`ifying the chartsPosition.

```
 positioner: function (w, h, point) {
    this.chart.pointer.chartPosition = null;
    return this.getPosition(w, h, point);
  },
```

This will force the chart to recalculate the charts position. Note that this might be DOM expensive.

Then, if you want to maintain the scrolling behaviour checkout @ppotaczeck's answer. The code below will remove any tooltips on scroll (works only for the first example)

```
document.body.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  Highcharts.charts[0].tooltip.hide(0);
}, true)
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gv1m6tjy/